# An element has order 2 in $S_n$ if and only if its cycle decomposition is a product of commuting 2-cycles

Tags: abstract-algebra, symmetric-groups

Prove that an element has order $2$ in $S_n$ if and only if its cycle decomposition is a product of commuting $2-$cycles.

I know the proof or how to solve it. But I am interested in how the disjoint cycle decomposition of these order $2$ elements is carried out.

In $S_n$, $(1, 2)$ is a order $2$ element. But what will be its  product of disjoint $2-$cycle decomposition?

Any help is appreciated. thanks.

Comment: It's just $(1, 2)$ itself, a product consisting of one cycle.

Comment: Its decomposition is its self. What the decomposition means is suppose you have a permeation $1 \mapsto 5$, $2 \mapsto 3$, $3 \mapsto 2$, $4 \mapsto 4$, $5 \mapsto 1$. Then this can written as $(1,5)(2,3)$ which is the product disjoint 2 cycles.

Comment: Okay now I understand what is happening.  Thanks @QiaochuYuan

Comment: Thanks @RishiSonthalia.